# Statement meaning

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

What does

```
  int(*compare)(void* argu1, void*argu2);
```

mean? I have never seen something like this, it is in my binary search tree chapter and is it in the BST strucutre:

```
typdef struct{
             int counter; 
             int(*compare)(void* argu1, void*argu2);
             NODE* root;
             }BST;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work

read about function pointers

Comment: Also, [the spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) is a useful tactic for parsing such syntax.

Answer (score 2):

This is a variable named `compare` which is a pointer to a function. The function returns an `int` and receives two `void *` parameters.

Function pointers are frequently used for providing a way to generically compare two values of a type that some other function (such as a sorting or ordering routine) does not understand; the caller provides a  function to do the comparison on the generic function's behalf.

Answer (score 1):

It means `compare` is a pointer to a function having its both parameter of type `void *` and having return type `int`.

Answer (score 1):

```
int(*compare)(void* argu1, void*argu2);
```

This is a variable declaration. The variable is a function pointer and its name is "compare". It can point to any function that returns an int and takes two void pointers.

Answer (score 0):

The code declares a variable named "compare". This variable is a function pointer type, meaning you can assign a function name to this variable, and later invoke this function just like making a regular function call. For further reading, you may refer to early binding vs. late binding.